# Is it too late to migrate Parse app to Parse server

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, migration, parse-server

I have the .json files from the Parse app in question. I never got to do the Migrate process as outlined in the image below:

[image]
I did however manage to export my classes prior to Parse shutting down. Is it possible to import the classes into MongoDB and connect it to the Parse Server project (as described in many of the resources) or is it too late (having missed the opportunity to run the Parse-built processes show above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Julien stated, you won't be able to retrieve your files, nor any data that isn't in your exports. However, you most certainly can import data into mongoDB using .JSON files.

What you'll want to do is follow the parse-server setup guide as if you're setting up a new parse-server instead of migrating. When you get it running, go to your dashboard and create all of your classes with their schema. Then, go to your Mongo instance and find the import commands. Import all your .jSON files for each class. You should be good to go, aside from those files.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth response. When you say "aside from those files" - what do you mean? I do have the JSON files for each Class in the Schema. If I follow your process, is that all the information I need to connect my client (iOS) to my server and retrieve data to the client? It makes sense that if you have a Parse Server/Mongodb instance, as long as the mongodb had the same schema and same data, and it was connected to the client, that it could work. However - I'm wondering if there were other required files that the Parse migration process generated that I can no longer obtain.

Comment: Setting up the Classes with their fields on the dashboard takes care of that.

As we stated, you have lost any file that you did not migrate off of Parse. They no longer have their file storage up. You can not get those back. The only other thing that you won't have is the indexes Parse sets up for you. Basically they help make database reads faster by sorting your data in various ways. This can drastically improve performance. Parse would automatically add these in a half intelligent manner.

Comment: It wasn't always perfect, but better than nothing. Though it would get overzealous, you don't want too many indexes because they make writes slower, as when things are updated it has to update the indexes. mLab will send you periodic emails suggesting indexes based on the queries you send, though, so if you pay attention to those and add the indexes over time, you'll see better performance. You can also read up on Indexes and set them up yourself before hand if you know what you'll be querying on

Answer (score 0):

If your files was on parse.com you can't retrieve your files.

I'm sorry for you

You can see this [post](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/a-parse-shutdown-reminder/)